# Submitting to Amazon Appstore with OpenIAB

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, amazon-appstore

We are using OpenIAB in our first Android app with in app purchase. We set everything up and are able to test successfully on the device using Amazon App Tester and installing the app using the ./adb install -i com.amazon.venezia appname.apk command in terminal.

When we submit to the Amazon Appstore, however, we are rejected by their testers as the app won't download the in app purchases/prices. I should comment it also works perfectly fine in Google Play, which uses OpenIAB also.

I've included the code we wrote below. We also set up the manifest and proguard-rules.pro as suggested by the web site. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated as we aren't getting anywhere with Amazon's support:

```
public class InAppBilling {
private static final String TAG = "InAppBilling";
private static InAppBilling mInstance = null;

// (arbitrary) request code for the purchase flow
static final int RC_REQUEST = <number goes here>;

private OpenIabHelper mHelper;
private NoteListFragment mFragment;
private Context mContext;

private InAppBilling() {}

public static InAppBilling get() {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        InAppConfig.init();
        mInstance = new InAppBilling();
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public OpenIabHelper getHelper() {
    return mHelper;
}

// Initialize OpenIAB library and when completed automatically kick off full product info download
public void init(Context context, NoteListFragment fragment) {
    mContext = context;

    // If library was already initialized, go straight to info download, don't init twice
    if (mHelper != null) {
        InAppBilling.get().queryPricesAndPurchases(fragment);
        return;
    }

    // Create the helper, passing it our context and the public keys to verify signatures with
    //Log.d(TAG, "Creating IAB helper.");
    OpenIabHelper.Options.Builder builder = new OpenIabHelper.Options.Builder()
            .setStoreSearchStrategy(OpenIabHelper.Options.SEARCH_STRATEGY_INSTALLER_THEN_BEST_FIT)
            .setVerifyMode(OpenIabHelper.Options.VERIFY_EVERYTHING)
            .addStoreKeys(InAppConfig.STORE_KEYS_MAP);
    mHelper = new OpenIabHelper(context, builder.build());

    // enable debug logging (for a production application, you should comment this out)
    //OpenIabHelper.enableDebugLogging(true);

    // Start setup. This is asynchronous and the embedded listener
    // will be called once setup completes.
    //Log.d(TAG, "Starting IAB setup.");
    mFragment = fragment;   // cache for use by callback
    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            //Log.d(TAG, "IAB Setup finished.");

            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                //Log.d(TAG, "Problem setting up in-app billing: " + result);
                mHelper = null;
                return;
            }

            //Log.d(TAG, "IAB Setup successful.");
            InAppBilling.get().queryPricesAndPurchases(null);   // use cached mFragment
        }
    });
}

// Launches a background download of info for all products
public void queryPricesAndPurchases(NoteListFragment fragment) {
    if (fragment != null)
        mFragment = fragment;
    //Log.d(TAG, "Launching product info query");
    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, InAppConfig.ALL_SKUS, mGotInventoryListener);
}

// Listener that's called when we finish querying the product info
// Sets the price info for all packs, and clears and then re-sets the notes' purchased states
private IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener =
        new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
                //Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished: " + inventory.getAllPurchases() + inventory.getAllOwnedSkus());
                if (result.isFailure()) {
                    //Log.d(TAG, "Failed to query inventory: " + result);
                    return;
                }
                //Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory was successful.");

                // Note & pack data controller singletons already exist (created at startup)
                // so we don't need to pass a Context here (which we don't really have handy)
                PackDataController pdc = PackDataController.get(null);
                NoteDataController ndc = NoteDataController.get(null);
                ndc.returnAllNotes();

                for (String sku : InAppConfig.ALL_SKUS) {
                    Pack pack = pdc.findPackWithAppStoreId(sku);
                    if (pack != null) {
                        if (inventory.hasDetails(sku)) {
                            SkuDetails details = inventory.getSkuDetails(sku);
                            String price = details.getPrice();
                            pack.setPrice(price);   // supposedly localized according to user's account
                            //Log.d(TAG, "SKU " + sku + " = " + price);
                        } else {
                            //Log.d(TAG, "SKU " + sku + " details not found");
                        }

                        if (inventory.hasPurchase(sku)) {
                            Purchase purchase = inventory.getPurchase(sku);
                            if (verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
                                //Log.d(TAG, "Purchased SKU " + sku);
                                ndc.purchaseNotesWithPackId(pack.getId(), true);
                            } else {
                                //Log.d(TAG, "Payload verification failed SKU " + sku);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                ndc.updateNoteList();
                mFragment.updateNoteAdapter();
            }
        };

/**
 * Verifies the developer payload of a purchase.
 */
boolean verifyDeveloperPayload(Purchase p) {
    String store = mHelper.getConnectedAppstoreName();
    if (store != null && store.equals(OpenIabHelper.NAME_AMAZON))
        return true;    // Amazon doesn't support payload verification, so bypass it
    if (p == null || p.getSku() == null)
        return false;
    String payload = p.getDeveloperPayload();
    if (payload == null)
        return false;

    return payload.equals(p.getSku() + p.getSku().length() * 13);
}

// Launches a product purchase request in a background thread
public void purchase(Activity act, String sku) {
    if (!sku.contains("."))
        sku = InAppConfig.SKU_PREFIX + sku;
    String payload = sku + sku.length() * 13;
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(act, sku, RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
}

// Callback for when a purchase is finished
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
        //Log.d(TAG, "Purchase finished: " + result + ", purchase: " + purchase);
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            //Log.d(TAG, "Error purchasing: " + result);
            return;
        }
        if (!verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
            //Log.d(TAG, "Error purchasing. Authenticity verification failed.");
            return;
        }

        //Log.d(TAG, "Purchase successful: " + purchase.getAppstoreName() + ", SKU: " + purchase.getSku());
        PackDataController pdc = PackDataController.get(null);
        Pack pack = pdc.findPackWithAppStoreId(purchase.getSku());
        NoteDataController ndc = NoteDataController.get(null);
        ndc.purchaseNotesWithPackId(pack.getId(), true);
        ndc.updateNoteList();
        if (mFragment != null)
            mFragment.updateNoteAdapter();

        Intent intent = new Intent("purchase-completed");
        // You can also include some extra data.
        intent.putExtra("message", "Purchase completed, reload template");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to double-check and make sure your in-app purchase items have been submitted and they are LIVE on Amazon Developer Console.

Amazon App Tester allows you to test in the sandbox environment. From my experience, it does not fully replicate the production environment. So even you were able to test successfully with App Tester, I would recommend you to test in the actual production environment with their [Live App Testing](https://developer.amazon.com/public/resources/development-tools/live-app-testing) service.

Comment: Thanks, Christina. Good to know regarding the App Tester. I'll perform the Live App Testing next. The in app purchases are live.